# How can a suspended user ask a question?

Tags: support

One of today's questions looks like it's been asked by a suspended user -- the user has 1 rep point and the account profile says the account is temporarily suspended. How is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A suspended account cannot post new questions. What happened was that the user created another account to evade suspension. When such cases are discovered, the offending accounts are often merged into the master account that's still under suspension.

The post ownership is transfered to the master account during the merge and thus the post looks as if it were made by a suspended account.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thanks for posting the question and answer and educating us.

Comment: Is this *really* working? [Goma](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/26782/goma) has allegedly been suspended for months, yet he has posted 20 questions in the last couple of weeks - 19 of which have been closed for being off-topic, non-constructive, duplicates, etc. Is he really creating new accounts regularly to evade his suspension? If so, is there any further activity that can be taken? IP block?

Comment: @Carson It's a little ... complicated. There are multiple IP addresses involved and banning each one individually is not feasible. We're currently taking a "moderate the questions as they come and merge users when we find them" approach.

Comment: @Carson63000: It's amusing to me that Goma is _still_ suspended ^_^

Comment: @PreferenceBean only until December 2017!